# Compatible in lenovo a369i

Tags: android, gps

I have uploaded my app on the Google playstore but why my app is not Compatible in my smartphone lenove a369i. Please let me know the reason. Please have a look on below androidmenifest code.

```
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />   need to discuss -->

<permission
    android:name="com.girnarsoft.cardekho.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.girnarsoft.cardekho.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Hi @Zahid Naqvi, did you resolve the issue, I am getting this issue..Please help me. Whats the issue.